# $t^{\nu}K_{\nu}(\beta t)$ The solution to an unknown ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions

Good day to you all,

This question is fairly open, so I hope that I'm not in breach of any of the Stack Exchange rules.

Clearly $f(t)=K_{\nu}(\beta t)$, where K is the modified Bessel function of the second kind, is a solution to Kelvin's equation. [Which is the modified Bessel equation with a small tweak]

I'm interested to know if anyone has come across a physically meaningful ODE (like Kelvin's equation \ Bessel equations etc) that has a solution of the form

\begin{equation}
t^{\nu}K_{\nu}(\beta t)
\end{equation}

Cheers,
Allen.

Comment: I have found an answer here!

http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0207.pdf

I'm not sure if the etiquette is to close the question or leave it here if anyone's interested in the answer.